# Use of custom make in eclipse IDE for C project

Tags: c, makefile, eclipse-cdt

I already have a makefile project in C. There are multiple makefiles that are used through the command line to help automate the build process as multiple folders are available in the project.

How can the same makefiles be used in my Eclipse project for building / compiling the code?

Answer (score 0):

Create a "Makefile project with existing code". Its project tree will include all the makefiles, given that they have common names.

Then use the view "Build targets" (menu "Windows" > "Show Views" > "Other") to create build targets in the respective directories. Please read its [documentation](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/reference/cdt_o_views.htm) to make the most of it. It is generally a good idea to read at least some of the introducing articles of the built-in help (menu "Help" > "Help Contents").

You might want to visit the project's or the general preferences for the build tool. For example, I like to unset "Stop on first build error" to get the make option `-k`.

I use this regularly, and it works really perfectly.

*Note 1: If you deselect the standard make tool when you create a new target, you can even change the build command. On Windows you can even enter the name of a batch file, or any other tool. These build targets are really versatile.*

*Note 2: This [Tutorial: Makefile Projects with Eclipse](https://mcuoneclipse.com/2017/07/22/tutorial-makefile-projects-with-eclipse/) shows some of this in a nutshell.*

Comment: When you say "Build Targets" view can you please help where exactly this could be found ? and secondly, could you please help with the exact documentation that you are referring to !!